# Cannot re declare block scoped variable error when I am not re-declaring it anywhere in my file

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I get an error that says `error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'packageList'` in a file named `package-list.ts` that has the following code:

```
const packageList = {
    'FREE': 'free',
    'GOLD': 'gold',
    'SILVER': 'silver',
    'BRONZE': 'bronze',
    'STARTER': 'starter'
}

module.exports = packageList;
```

with the `tsc` compiler options:

```
    {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2015",
        "outDir": "../dist",
        "allowJs": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noEmitOnError": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "strictNullChecks": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

I have not redeclared `packageList` anywhere in the above code. What could then be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `packageList` is being used by some other module. You can try following options:

**Solution 1**

Change the name `packageList` to `myPackageList`.

**Solution 2.**

Don't include DOM typings. To do this, add an explicit lib property in your tsconfig.json that does not include `dom`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "es2015"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Solution 3.**

Try by adding `export {};` at top.